# why does draw vector layer can not seen on map after drawend on openlayer React app?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, draw, interaction

I have a map project which is created on React framework with Openlayers.
I try to use draw interaction with my map and i am having problem to show the interaction result on map after draw, but there is a weird issue about it, it suddenly disappear from map after drawend.
Its code block is as shown below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext } from 'react'
import MapContext from '../contexts/MapContext';
import './Measure.css'
import { Layer as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source'
import { Draw as OLdraw } from 'ol/interaction'

// import { Style, Stroke, Fill, Circle, Text, Image, Icon, RegularShape, IconImage } from 'ol/style'
// import { Feature, Overlay as OLOverlay } from 'ol';
// import { LineString, Point, Polygon } from 'ol/geom';
// import { toLonLat } from 'ol/proj';
// import { getArea, getLength, getDistance } from 'ol/sphere'


export default function Measure() {

    const map = useContext(MapContext)

    const [drawType, setdrawType] = useState();
    const overlayRef = useRef();
    const [toggleOn, setToggleOn] = useState(false);
    const [source, setSource] = useState(new VectorSource({ wrapX: false }));

    useEffect(() => {
        let drawLayer = new VectorLayer({ source, map, zIndex: 10000, visible: true });
        map.addLayer(drawLayer);
    }, [])


    useEffect(() => {
        let draw;
        switch (drawType) {
            case 'Point':
                draw = new OLdraw({ type: drawType, stopClick: true, source })
                break;
            case 'LineString':
                draw = new OLdraw({ type: drawType, stopClick: true, source })
                break;
            case 'Polygon':
                draw = new OLdraw({ type: drawType, stopClick: true, source })
                break;
            case 'None':
                break;
            case 'Undefined':
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (draw) {
            map.addInteraction(draw);
        }

    }, [drawType])


    const toggleHandle = () => {
        toggleOn ? setToggleOn(false) : setToggleOn(true);
    };

    const handleDrawType = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.getAttributeNode("value").value;
        setdrawType(value);
    }

    return (
        <div className="draw">
            <div ref={overlayRef}></div>
            <div className='measurement'>
                <div className='toggle' onClick={toggleHandle}>
                    <span><img src='./assets/measure/measure.svg'></img></span>
                </div>
                {toggleOn ?
                    <div className='options' onClick={handleDrawType}>
                        <span><img src='./assets/measure/point.svg' value="Point"></img></span>
                        <span><img src='./assets/measure/area.svg' value="LineString"></img></span>
                        <span><img src='./assets/measure/polyline.svg' value="Polygon"></img></span>
                        <span><img src='./assets/measure/trash.svg' value="None"></img></span>
                    </div> : null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Draw interaction result disappear after drawend.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of React lifecycle management problems. You use `useEffect()` to add Openlayers components to a map that is external to your component. You never remove them. You will end up creating components every time React updates your component.

Wrapping Openlayers in a React component is not trivial. Generally, you have to use class-based components and manage the whole lifecycle yourself.

As the author of rlayers I suggest you to try to look for inspiration there: https://mmomtchev.github.io/rlayers/#/draw

Comment: I specified its source when defining the vector layer and drawing interaction. How can I do this further? This is how it's done in the examples on Openlayers' page.(https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html) And I used my MapContext to show my other layers, I made my popups using this MapContext again.

Comment: Yes indeed, I didn't see it the first time. Still, you are depending on the order in which `useEffect` will get called. `useEffect` is a bad choice to implement this. Try adding `console.log` in each `useEffect` to see what happens. I don't know how will Openlayers react to multiple `Draw` interactions - because this is what you are doing.